# TinyMCE set view -> show blocks

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

i like the show blocks feature under view - is there a way i can set it on as default when the editor loads

THank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want to set the `visualblocks_default_state` to true?

The documentation is your friend on this question:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/visualblocks/#visualblocks_default_state

Comment: thanks man, very obvious i did read the docs just not all of it :)